# Find the number of ways to color a tetrahedron

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Given a tetrahedron, we may color it's faces with $3$ colors, blue, red, and green. We want to find some rotation based symmetries by using $SO(4).$ We define a genuinely different possibility for a tetrahedron if after a rotation it will be different in respect to the colors. How many such genuinely different possibilities are there?

In order to answer the question, I would like to use the Burnside lemma which is relating the total number of fixed points under the action of the group and the order of the group $SO(4)$ to the total number of orbits. Given that orbits partition the set on which the group is acting, the total number of orbits will be equal to the number of the genuinely different possibilities we are looking for. For each element of the group I thus need to find the set of fixed points given that action. The identity element of the group corresponds to fixing all the elements of the set. Thus, this amounts to finding the number of possibilities to color a tetrahedron with colors such that each color appears at least once.

Here is the question I wanted originally to post here:

Given a tetrahedron that we place on a table in how many ways one can color it's sides such that each color appears at least once?

Since the number of options is low, one can find them by going from case to case, but I wanted a more analytic way, sort of a combinatorics approach.

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Up to what symmetries?

Comment: If all three colors must appear, then exactly two faces are the same color, while the other faces are different colors.  The two faces which are the same color must be contiguous.

Comment: I need to use this in a problem where the number of genuinely different possibilities of coloring a tetrahedron is asked. A genuinely different possibility is one in which given the action of $SO(4)$, that is rotations along some axis, there will be no overlap of the colors.

Comment: What's "overlap of the colors"?

Comment: A tetrahedron prior and after a rotation should not be the same concerning the colors of the corresponding faces. Ultimately, I need to use the Burnside lemma.

Comment: Then you should edit that into the question. People shouldn't have to read through all these comments to understand what the question is about.

Comment: Is it coloring the faces, edges, or vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group of rotations of a tetrahedron splits up into three types:

- $8$ rotations of $120^o$ about a vertex. This gives two face orbits (a 3-cycle and a fixed face).
- $3$ rotations of $180^o$ about a vertex. This gives two face orbits (two 2-cycles).
- $1$ identity rotation. This has four face orbits (all fixed).

If you have $c$ paint colours available, you have $c^4$ ways of painting the $4$ faces of a tetrahedron. If you apply Burnside's Lemma or whatever you want to call it, you get $N(c)=(c^4+11c^2)/12$ colourings when rotations are discounted, because under 11 of the 12 rotations there are exactly 2 orbits.

So we get $N(1)=1$, $N(2)=5$, and $N(3)=15$ tetrahedra for $c=1,2,3$ available paint colours.

If you want to use exactly $2$ paint colours, then there are $N(2)-\binom{2}{1}\cdot N(1) = 5-2 = 3$ possible tetrahedra colourings because the $N(2)$ value includes monochrome ones, and there are $\binom{2}{1}$ ways to choose their colour from the available paints.

With that we can now find  the number of tetrahedra with exactly $3$ colours, namely $N(3)-\binom{3}{2}\cdot 4 -\binom{3}{1}\cdot 1 = 15-12-1 = 3$. This is because there are $\binom{3}{2}\cdot 4$ tetrahedra with exactly two of the three paint colours on them ($\binom{3}{2}$ paint choices, each in $4$ arrangements).

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather naive answer ...

Let's say the colors are
$ \{ \text{red},\text{blue},\text{green},\text{green} \}$ =$\{\text{R},\text{B},\text{G},\text{G}\}.$

Put a green (G) face on the table.  Now there are 3!=6 ways to color the three faces.  But we could have originally painted any face green (G).  So multiply by 4.  But we've double counted $ (G_1,G_2)=(G_2,G_1)$ so divide by 2.  There are 3 colors that we could have started with $\{R,B,G\}$.

Number of ways = $\frac{6\cdot 4 \cdot 3 }{2} = 36.$

### UPDATE

That assumes rotations matter.  Reading the comments (and re-reading the question), it appears that you want to divide by the number of rotations.  In that case, there is only three colors, and for each color that appears twice, there is a solution and it's mirror image:

Number of ways not counting rotations = $3\cdot 2 = 6.$

To explain:  If there are two green faces, place the green face on the table.  Now color another face green.  There are only two possibilities:  $\{(R,B),(B,R)\}$.  That's it for two greens (2 solutions), same for each of the other two colors.

### Another Update

Got some help in the comments!  There are only 3 colorings (one coloring for each "double color").

Comment: When you have two faces the same colour, you can rotate it to swap the other two coloured faces, so their order does not matter. I.e. just place the other green face on the table. It is symmetric, so there is no mirror image.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis,  You are right!  Thank you!  There are only 3 ways!